# Spinner checkbox box state get false while scroll down item and not updating adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

1. i have custom `Spinner` with one `TextView` and one `CheckBox`. i am adding item to spinner through adapter. while i checked checkbox again it get uncheck or checked position got change.
2. I have two `Array` from the data coming from i.e product_30 or product_80
3. from both `Array` what ever the item selected by spinner should be display in `EditText`.

code

**Array :**

```
 <string-array name="product_2_30">

        <item>A</item>
        <item>B</item>
        <item>C</item>
        <item>D</item>
        <item>E</item>
        <item>N</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="product_2_80">        
        <item>A1</item>
        <item>B2</item>
        <item>C3</item>
        <item>D4</item>
        <item>F5</item>
        <item>NN</item>
</string-array>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pankajkumar.adaptertest.MainActivity">


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/item_2_30"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/item_2_80"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="80" />
    </RadioGroup>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinerlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rgGroup"
        android:background="@drawable/insect_test"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/myspinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="showDropDown"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/drop_down_arrow" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_itemList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinerlayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] item_2_30, item_2_80;
    private Spinner mSpinner;
    private MyBaseAdapter adapter_30, adapter_80;
    public static ArrayList<Modal> modals_2_30, modals_2_80;
    private RadioGroup group;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
        item_2_30 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.product_2_30);
        item_2_80 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.product_2_80);
        group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgGroup);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_itemList);

        modals_2_30 = AddItemToSpinner.addItem(item_2_30);
        modals_2_80 = AddItemToSpinner.addItem(item_2_80);

        adapter_30 = new MyBaseAdapter(this, modals_2_30, editText);
        adapter_80 = new MyBaseAdapter(this, modals_2_80, editText);

        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter_30);


        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                switch (i) {
                    case R.id.item_2_30:
                        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter_30);
                        break;
                    case R.id.item_2_80:
                        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter_80);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void showDropDown(View view) {
        mSpinner.performClick();
    }


}
```

**MyBaseAdapter.java**

```
    public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "MyBaseAdapter";
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Modal> modals;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private EditText editText;
    private int count = 1;
    private int po;

    public MyBaseAdapter(MainActivity mContext, ArrayList<Modal> modals, EditText editText) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.modals = modals;
        this.editText = editText;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unregisterDataSetObserver: ");
        addSelectedItem(MainActivity.modals_2_30);
        addSelectedItem(MainActivity.modals_2_80);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        po = position;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);
            holder.txt_item_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_name);
            holder.chk_check_item = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_item_check);
            view.setTag(holder);
            view.setTag(R.id.txt_item_name, holder.txt_item_name);
            view.setTag(R.id.chk_item_check, holder.chk_check_item);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.txt_item_name.setText(modals.get(position).getListItem());
        holder.chk_check_item.setChecked(modals.get(position).isCheck());

        holder.chk_check_item.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                modals.get(po).setCheck(b);
            }
        });

        holder.txt_item_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //int getposition1 = (Integer) view.getTag();
                if (modals.get(po).isCheck()) {
                    modals.get(po).setCheck(false);
                } else {
                    modals.get(po).setCheck(true);
                }

            }
        });
       // notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modals.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        po = position;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, viewGroup, false);
            holder.txt_item_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_name);
            holder.chk_check_item = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_item_check);
            view.setTag(holder);
            view.setTag(R.id.txt_item_name, holder.txt_item_name);
            view.setTag(R.id.chk_item_check, holder.chk_check_item);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.txt_item_name.setText(modals.get(position).getListItem());
        holder.chk_check_item.setChecked(modals.get(position).isCheck());

//        holder.chk_check_item.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
//                modals.get(po).setCheck(b);
//            }
//        });
//
//        holder.txt_item_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                //int getposition1 = (Integer) view.getTag();
//                if (modals.get(po).isCheck()) {
//                    modals.get(po).setCheck(false);
//                } else {
//                    modals.get(po).setCheck(true);
//                }
//
//            }
//        });

       // notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_item_name;
        CheckBox chk_check_item;
    }

    public void addSelectedItem(ArrayList<Modal> modals) {
        for (Modal m : modals) {
            if (m.isCheck()) {
                editText.setText(m.getListItem() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in getDropDownView method you are getting position for the spinner item not the list position. So when you are updating value in your List its getting wrong

Comment: how i can get original position. i m geting last index which id visible in screen

Comment: How you are setting data into spinner?

Comment: by using adapter which is given above.

Answer (score 0):

Since CheckBox (eventually) extends View, you can use a standard `OnClickListener` to detect when the CheckBox is actually tapped by the user Instead of `CheckedChangeListener`

```
holder.chk_check_item
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                        //Checkbox is checked Perform logic here
                    } else {

                    }


                }
            });
```

Checked change Listener does not hold checks properly on scrolling so that is why your checkbox states get changed while scrolling. Try it and let me know. It worked for me ..

Answer (score 0):

Modal class

```
public class Modal {
    private boolean isCheck;
    private String listItem;

    public boolean isCheck() {
        return isCheck;
    }

    public void setCheck(boolean check) {
        isCheck = check;
    }

    public String getListItem() {
        return listItem;
    }

    public void setListItem(String listItem) {
        this.listItem = listItem;
    }
}
```

//==========Adapter class ======================

```
    public class MyNewSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "MyNewSpinnerAdapter";
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Modal> modals;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private EditText editText;
    private int count = 1;
    private int po;
    private Spinner mSpinner;

    public MyNewSpinnerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Modal> modals, EditText editText, Spinner mSpinner) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.modals = modals;
        this.editText = editText;
        this.mSpinner = mSpinner;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getDropDownView: " + position);
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, viewGroup, false);
            holder.txt_item_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_name);
            holder.chk_check_item = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_item_check);
            view.setTag(holder);
            view.setTag(R.id.txt_item_name, holder.txt_item_name);
            view.setTag(R.id.chk_item_check, holder.chk_check_item);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.txt_item_name.setText(modals.get(position).getListItem());
        holder.chk_check_item.setChecked(modals.get(position).isCheck());
        holder.chk_check_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Drop Down " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (modals.get(position).isCheck()) {
                    modals.get(position).setCheck(false);
                } else {
                    AddItemToSpinner.refreshData(NewProductSelectionActivity.type);
                    modals.get(position).setCheck(true);
                    if (mSpinner != null) {
                        try {
                            Method method = Spinner.class.getDeclaredMethod("onDetachedFromWindow");
                            method.setAccessible(true);
                            method.invoke(mSpinner);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {
        editText.getText().clear();
        updateData();
    }

    public void updateData() {
        for (Modal m : NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_30) {

            if (m.isCheck()) {
                editText.append(m.getListItem() + "\n");
            }
        }
        for (Modal m : NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_80) {
            if (m.isCheck()) {
                editText.append(m.getListItem() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modals.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return modals.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, viewGroup, false);
            holder.txt_item_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_name);
            holder.chk_check_item = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_item_check);
            view.setTag(holder);
            view.setTag(R.id.txt_item_name, holder.txt_item_name);
            view.setTag(R.id.chk_item_check, holder.chk_check_item);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.txt_item_name.setText(modals.get(position).getListItem());
        holder.chk_check_item.setChecked(modals.get(position).isCheck());
        return view;

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_item_name;
        CheckBox chk_check_item;
    }
}
```

//====================Add item to list========================

```
    public class AddItemToSpinner {
    public static ArrayList<Modal> addItem(String[] item) {
        ArrayList<Modal> modals = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : item) {
            Modal m = new Modal();
            m.setListItem(s);
            m.setCheck(false);
            modals.add(m);
        }
        return modals;
    }


    public static void refreshData(String typeList) {
        if (typeList.equals("2_30")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_30.size(); i++) {
                if (NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_30.get(i).isCheck()) {
                    NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_30.get(i).setCheck(false);
                }
            }
        } else if (typeList.equals("2_80")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_80.size(); i++) {
                if (NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_80.get(i).isCheck()) {
                    NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_80.get(i).setCheck(false);
                }

            }
        } else if (typeList.equals("All")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_30.size(); i++) {
                if (NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_30.get(i).isCheck()) {
                    NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_30.get(i).setCheck(false);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_80.size(); i++) {
                if (NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_80.get(i).isCheck()) {
                    NewProductSelectionActivity.modals_2_80.get(i).setCheck(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//=========================MainActivity.java===================================

```
    public class NewProductSelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] item_2_30, item_2_80;
    public static String type = "2_30";
    private Spinner mSpinner;
    private MyNewSpinnerAdapter adapter_30, adapter_80;
    public static ArrayList<Modal> modals_2_30, modals_2_80;
    private RadioGroup group;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
        item_2_30 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.product_2_30);
        item_2_80 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.product_2_80);
        group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgGroup);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_itemList);
        modals_2_30 = AddItemToSpinner.addItem(item_2_30);
        modals_2_80 = AddItemToSpinner.addItem(item_2_80);
        adapter_30 = new MyNewSpinnerAdapter(this, modals_2_30, editText,mSpinner);
        adapter_80 = new MyNewSpinnerAdapter(this, modals_2_80, editText,mSpinner);
        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter_30);
        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                switch (i) {
                    case R.id.item_2_30:
                        type = "2_30";
                        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter_30);
                        break;
                    case R.id.item_2_80:
                        type = "2_80";
                        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter_80);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });


        findViewById(R.id.btnrefresh).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                type = "All";
                AddItemToSpinner.refreshData(type);
                adapter_30.unregisterDataSetObserver(null);
            }
        });
    }

    public void showDropDown(View view) {
        mSpinner.performClick();


    }
}
```

Now it's working.. :D